# How to subclass QGLWidget to use glew?

Tags: qt, qt5, glew, qglwidget

I'm struggling to get a subclass of QGLWidget compiled that uses glew. I'm running Qt 5.0.1 + MinGW 4.7 on Windows 7. Glew 1.7.0 has been compiled with said MinGW.

I have subclassed QGLWidget with UGGLWidget and included `"GL/glew.h"` before the QGLWidget includes. When compiling I get 200 Errors about:

- 'function' *redeclared as different kind of symbol*
- *conflicting declaration* 'typedef'

So my Question:
**How do I get a subclass of QGLWidget that uses glew compiled under Qt5?**

---

Edit: I tried the same approach with another setup (Qt4.7 + MinGW4.4). It compiles and runs just fine. I have also tried using a more recent version of glew (Qt5.0.1 + MinGW4.7 + glew1.9.0) this doesn't compile either and gives the same compilation errors.

---

Here's a messy snippet of the compiler output:

```
> In file included from
> ..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include/QtGui/qopengl.h:55:0,
>                  from ..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtOpenGL/qgl.h:47,
>                  from ..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtOpenGL/QGLWidget:1,
>                  from src\UGGLWidget.h:4,
>                  from src\UGGLWidget.cpp:2: ..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include/GLES2/gl2.h:614:153:
> error: 'void __glewVertexAttribPointer(GLuint, GLint, GLenum,
> GLboolean, GLsizei, const GLvoid*)' redeclared as different kind of
> symbol In file included from src\UGGLWidget.cpp:1:0:
> ..\3rdPartyLibs\glew\include/GL/glew.h:13609:46: error: previous
> declaration of 'void (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *
> __glewVertexAttribPointer)(GLuint, GLint, GLenum, GLboolean, GLsizei, const GLvoid*)'
```

Last but not least the header and source file of the subclass. It's really just empty for now.

Source:

```
//UGGLWidget.cpp
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "UGGLWidget.h"

UGGLWidget::UGGLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) { ... }
```

Header:

```
//UGGLWidget.h
#ifndef UGGLWIDGET_H
#define UGGLWIDGET_H
#include <QGLWidget>

class UGGLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UGGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
#endif // UGGLWIDGET_H
```

Oh, and maybe relevant parts from the .pro file

```
QT       += core gui opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
LIBS += -L$$quote(../3rdPartyLibs/glew/lib/) -lglew32
LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglu32
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(../3rdPartyLibs/glew/include)
```

Comment: Did you initialise GLEW? http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html

Comment: @cmannett85 Yes, I do in initializeGL(). Though my problem already lies in compiling the subclass. glewInit() should only matter at runtime.  I will clarify this in the question, thanks.

Comment: I tried ditching glew alltogether and putting my bets on the QGLWidget providing all the functionality I need, but this failed as well. glPointSize, glDeleteVertexArrays and other functions regarding vertex arrays are not declared inside the scope of a QGLWidget.

Comment: What version of OpenGL does your graphics card drivers support?

Comment: @cmannett85 It supports opengl 4.2. I have an application using opengl 3.3 core profile that runs just fine with freeglut/glew. I wanted to move this application to Qt. For a current 'workaround' I went back to Qt4.7. I'm still wondering what's going wrong with Qt5.0.1 and my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fixed my problem, this goes everywhere, where I include glew:

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2
```

Another option: building Qt5.0.1 from source with `-opengl desktop` during the configure step.

---

For some reason `QT_OPENGL_ES_2` is defined in my Qt5.0.1 installation. Looking through the inlcudes from QGLWidget.h I found the following in *QtCore/qconfig.h*

```
#if defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2) && defined(QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2)
# undef QT_OPENGL_ES_2
#elif !defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)
# define QT_OPENGL_ES_2
#endif
```

This leads to inclusion of *GLES2/gl2.h* which doesn't get along with glew. Knowing that the issue was related to GLES2 I came across a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28821?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel) and a [QtProject post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23459).
If I understand correctly, then the provided QtSDK installer for Qt5.0.1 has been built such that GLES is enabled.

Have a good day,
~Moritz

Answer (score 2):

Note that QT 4.8RC release notes say:
 Including QtOpenGL will not work in combination with GLEW, as QGLFunctions will undefine GLEW's defines.